# Regular expression to match base path

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

I'm trying to come out with a regular expression to match a certain base path. The rule should be to match the base path itself plus a "/" or a "." and the rest of the path.

for example, given /api/ping, the following should match

```
/api/ping.json
/api/ping
/api/ping/xxx/sss.json
/api/ping.xml
```

and this should NOT match

```
/api/pingpong
/api/ping_pong
/api/ping-pong
```

I tried with the following regexp:

```
/api/ping[[\.|\/].*]?
```

But it doesn't seem to catch the `/api/ping` case

Here is the a [link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2fapi%2fping%5b%5b%5c.%7c%5c%2f%7c%5c%3f%5d.*%5d%3f&i=%2fapi%2fping.json%0d%0a%2fapi%2fping%0d%0a%2fapi%2fping%2fxxx%2fsss.json%0d%0a%2fapi%2fping.xml%0d%0a%2fapi%2fping%3fxml%3dtrue%0d%0a%2fapi%2fpingpong%0d%0a%2fapi%2fping_pong%0d%0a%2fapi%2fping-pong) to regex storm tester

--

update: thanks to the answers, now I have this version that reflects better my reasoning:

```
\/api\/ping(?:$|[.\/?]\S*)
```

The expression either ends after ping (that's the `$` part) or continues with a `.`, `/` or `?` followed by any non-space characters

here's the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/TfaD7n/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex which uses alternations to ensure the base path is followed by either a `.` or `/` or end of line `$`

```
\/api\/ping(?=\.|\/|$)\S*
```

**Explanation:**

- `\/api\/ping` - Matches `/api/ping` text literally
- `(?=\.|\/|$)` - Look ahead ensuring what follows is either a literal dot `.` or a slash `/` or end of line `$`
- `\S*` - Optionally follows whatever non-space character follows the path

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TfaD7n/1)**

In your regex, `/api/ping[[\.|\/].*]?` usage of character set `[]` is not correct, where you don't need to escape a dot `.` and alternation `|` isn't needed in a character set and can't be done by placing `|` within character class, and also as the character class looks nested, it isn't required and not the right thing to do. I guess you wanted to make your regex something like this,

```
\/api\/ping([.\/].*)?$
```

**[Demo with your corrected regex](https://regex101.com/r/TfaD7n/3)**

Notice, once you place anything in `[]` then it is only counted as one character allowing everything contained within character set, hence it allows either a dot `.` or slash `/` and notice you need to escape `/` as `\/`

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, thanks to your explanation I built a version that reflects better my reasoning. On the other hand, I don't quite understand the difference between a look ahead and a non-capturing group.

Comment: @opensas: A non-grouping capture is the one having `?:` immediately after `(` and is actually redundant in terms of functionality, i.e. it doesn't change the meaning of regex at all. It just makes the regex more performant as then the regex doesn't have to record what got captured in a group so only make a group as non-capture if you don't need the group text. On the other hand look ahead which is denoted by this `(?=` is used to confirm that the text lying ahead matches the regex present inside the group and does not consume any characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern uses a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) that will match any of the listed which could also be written as `[[./|]`.

It does not match `/api/ping` because the the character class has to match at least 1 time as it is not optional.

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to  match `/api/ping` followed by asserting the end of the string or `|` match the structure by repeating 0 or more times matching a forward slash followed by not a forward slash followed by a dot and 1+ times  and then a dot and the extension.

```
/api/ping(?:(?:/[^/\s]+)*\.\S+|$)
```

That will match

- `/api/ping` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:/[^/\s]+)*` Repeat a grouping structure 0+ times matching `/` then 1+ times not `/` or a whitespace character
  - `\.\S+` Match a dot and 1+ times a non whitespace character
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close non capturing group

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BIhwZi/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/xuLruV)